# Parse CSV with Headers in defined in XML

Tags: c#, parsing, csv

I have a CSV file, whose headers are defined in separate XML as shown below.

```
<columns>
  <column value="FirstName" required="true"/>
  <column value="LastName" required="false"/>
  <column value="Age" required="true"/>
</columns>
```

I need to parse the CSV, check rules and save it. Effectively, I need to find that first column is FirstName, second column is LastName based on positions in XML rather than fixed position. I also have other rules which is like FirstName must be alphabets only, age can be number only which are based on column name and not position.

So, I need to get the data as per column name in XML and then apply rules.

Any pointer/idea will be helpful.

Comment: Pointer/idea: start writing code. When you get stuck, let us know what exactly your problem is.

Comment: Have you started with parsing the XML file?  How about starting there. This might be a good reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: What do you intend to save? What happens if the validation rules fail? You need to be more specific. And as a programmer you need to write code, not stackoverflow questions.

Comment: Your profile says you're a tech lead with 15 years of experience on the MS stack.....having an off day, perhaps?

Comment: @Discord: I have already done with reading XML, parsing CSV to string array. Thing which I could not figure out was header name which are in different file (XML). I was just looking for right idea for that.
@ Tim: Yup, one off day :-( When you have client pressure and working at 4 AM in the morning sometimes brain doesn't support.
Anyway, someone pointed me rightly to create a datatable, add columns using values in XML and then populate datatable with split strings. Which worked.
Thanks for reading question.

Answer (score -1):

Try code below to read CSV.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Xsl;

namespace CSVImporter
{

    public partial class CSVImporter : Form
    {
        //const string xmlfilename = @"C:\Users\fenwky\XmlDoc.xml";
        const string xmlfilename = @"C:\temp\test.xml";
        DataSet ds = null;
        public CSVImporter()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // Create a Open File Dialog Object.
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "csv files (*.csv)|*.csv|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            string fileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;


            //doc.InsertBefore(xDeclare, root);
            // Create a CSV Reader object.
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader();

            ds = reader.ReadCSVFile(fileName, true);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Table1"];

        }
        private void WXML_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WriteXML();

        }
        public void WriteXML()
        {

            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            ds.WriteXml(new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter), XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);

            string xmlStr = stringWriter.ToString();

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(xmlStr);


            XmlDeclaration xDeclare = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
            XmlNode docNode = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);

            doc.InsertBefore(xDeclare, doc.FirstChild);

            // Create a procesing instruction.
            //XmlProcessingInstruction newPI;
            //String PItext = "<abc:stylesheet xmlns:abc=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\" version=\"1.0\">";
            //String PItext = "type='text/xsl' href='book.xsl'";
            string PItext = "html xsl:version=\"1.0\" xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\"";
            XmlText newPI =  doc.CreateTextNode(PItext);
            //newPI = docCreateProcessingInstruction("html", PItext);
            //newPI = doc.CreateComment(CreateDocumentType("html", PItext, "", "");
            doc.InsertAfter(newPI, doc.FirstChild);
            doc.Save(xmlfilename);

            XslCompiledTransform myXslTrans = new XslCompiledTransform();
            myXslTrans.Load(xmlfilename);
            string directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(xmlfilename);
            myXslTrans.Transform(xmlfilename, directoryPath + "result.html");
            webBrowser1.Navigate(directoryPath + "result.html");

        }



    }
    public class CSVReader
    {

        public DataSet ReadCSVFile(string fullPath, bool headerRow)
        {

            string path = fullPath.Substring(0, fullPath.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
            string filename = fullPath.Substring(fullPath.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(fullPath))
                {
                    string ConStr = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0}" + ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR={1};FMT=Delimited\\\"", path, headerRow ? "Yes" : "No");
                    string SQL = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", filename);
                    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(SQL, ConStr);
                    adapter.Fill(ds, "TextFile");
                    ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Table1";
                }
                foreach (DataColumn col in ds.Tables["Table1"].Columns)
                {
                    col.ColumnName = col.ColumnName.Replace(" ", "_");
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            return ds;
        }
    }
}​
```

You can then save the DataTable to XML

```
           DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);

            ds.WriteXml("Filename", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);


            // read columns of datatable
            List<string> headers = new List<string>();
            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                headers.Add(column.ColumnName);

                // type can be gotten from this
                Type columnType = column.DataType;
            }​
```